# how to create Toolbar in window Application using C#

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, toolbar, thick-client

i want to create toolbar using window application in dotnet.it will use yahoo,gmail API.
please anybody have any solution pls send me.

Answer (score 2):

Drag a "ToolStrip" control from the Toolbox on to your Form.

Here's some doc: [ToolStrip Technology Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5swc13h.aspx).